# Generic Data Type for Enum throwing error

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-3.8

If I tried to define enums of Generic data type it throws an error

For example:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class GenericClass(Generic[T]):
    pass


class Foo(GenericClass, Enum):
    ONE = GenericClass[int]
    TWO = GenericClass[str]


print(Foo.ONE)  # Fails on python 3.7 with ValueError: __main__.GenericClass[int] is not a valid Foo
```

Error :

```
File "/Users/aivanov/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 569, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/aivanov/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 553, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "/Users/aivanov/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 582, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: __main__.GenericClass[int] is not a valid Foo
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Is this your whole code? I just copied it to a python script and added the imports. It runs through but obviously doesn't really do much. Do you do something at another point in your code which may actually raise the error?

Comment: Hi @schilli , I have edited the example to better reproduce my issue. 
Note that the code does not work on python3.7 or python3.8. But it works on python3.9

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `CPython < 3.9` coming from a combination of `typing.py` and `enum.py`.

More specifically, the error comes from creating a generic subclass with an enum, such as:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class Base(Generic[T]):
    ...


class Foo(Base[int], Enum):
    x = 0  # Causes an error.
    ...
```

In `CPython = 3.9`, this was unintentionally fixed in [Remove the `__new__` method of `typing.Generic`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/21327), which reveals the actual error comes from [Enum: Supported dunder names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names):

> `__new__()`, if specified, must create and return the enum members; it is also a very good idea to set the member’s `_value_` appropriately. Once all the members are created it is no longer used.

This is a conflict of interests. Enum members are special objects where creating them using a different `__new__` is a whole can of worms it would seem.

That said, there are two approaches to fixing the problem in this case:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

# Option 1:
if hasattr(Generic, "__new__"):  # It never did anything other than"protecting"
    del Generic.__new__          # you from directly instantiating it.

T = TypeVar("T")


class Foo(Generic[T]):
    ...


class Bar(Foo[int], Enum):
    # Option 2:
    __new__ = object.__new__  # If the `__new__` method can be replaced
                              # with `object.__new__`, then use it instead.
```

The first option is specific to handling `typing.Generic`, while the second option applies more generally to any parent that has a custom `__new__` implementation you want to ignore.

See also: [this issue thread](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101809).